# Auto resize graphic to fit into container when in landscape (CSS, java, html5 only)

Tags: html, landscape, autoresize

I have searched through Stack Overflow questions to make sure I'm not being redundant, and though many of the previously asked questions were similar I did not understand exactly what was being asked nor did I understand the answers.

My question is this:

I am using Intel XDK to create an HTML5 app. When I view my page in landscape mode, the graphic I'm using stretches outside of the container. What code should I add to make the graphic resize to fit within the container AND where do I add the code?

If I was able to post a screenshot, I would (I don't have 10 pts yet). You would be able to see the graphic stretches outside of the container when viewed in the landscape toggle. I need this graphic to stay in the container when in landscape.

Can you provide recommended code (Java, CSS, or HTML5 only please) to auto resize the image, or what have you, and also please specify where the code should be added in my `index.html` file. If it is a CSS style property, please likewise say so - Intel XDK makes it really easy to add style properties to elements using design mode.

Comment: You can view a screen shot at this link: https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=6326

Comment: Update: I created a fully functioning responsive app using html5, css3 and a java file. The key I found is finding a decent template and adjusting it to what you want. In this way you do not rely on software to assist you, which only adds cluttered code. I made a series of slow running apps before I decided to just use code and Intel XDK for packaging. I think that works best.